# How to post a url same as facebook in asp.net mvc4,?so that if i click on url it opens in new tab?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

How to post a url same as post a comment in asp.net mvc4 like as in facebook ?so that if i click on url it opens in new tab?

Answer (score 0):

You can add attribute

```
<a target="_blank"> </a>
```

It will open in new tab.